# How to define a token which is all those characters in set A, except those in sub-set B?

Tags: antlr4, lexer

In [RFC2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) (HTTP/1.1) the definition of a 'token' in section '2.2 Basic Rules' is given as:

```
token          = 1*<any CHAR except CTLs or separators>
```

From that section, I've got the following fragments, and now I want to define 'TOKEN':

```
lexer grammar AcceptEncoding;

TOKEN: /* (CHAR excluding (CTRL | SEPARATORS)) */

fragment CHAR: [\u0000-\u007f];
fragment CTRL: [\u0000-\u001f] | \u007f;
fragment SEPARATORS: [()<>@,;:\\;"/\[\]?={|}] | SP | HT;
fragment SP: ' ';
fragment HT: '\t';
```

How do I approximate my hypothetical 'excluding' operator for the definition of `TOKEN`?

Comment: Actually, as hinted in my grammar name, what I really want is an ANTLR grammar for parsing the 'Accept-Encoding' header of HTTP/1.1, but I can't find one?!

Comment: I realise I can probably 'do the math' and split up the entire ASCII 0-127 range into discrete regions, such that I only ever need to combine them using the '|' operator.  But then, RFC2616 pulls the 'excluding' trick in multiple places, and I might not be able to break it down sufficiently to satisfy all of them at once?  Just worried about proceeding in this direction only to find a dead end.

Comment: For the question in your title, look at the `~` operator. ex. `MYTOKEN: ~[ab]` will match any character not described by a or b, where a or b can be a character, fragment, or whatever. A good example of this in use is your typical comment: `COMMENT : '#' ~[\r\n]* '\r'? '\n' -> skip ;` edit: I just realized this is not a new question, sorry

Answer (score 1):

There is no set/range math in ANTLR. You can only combine several sets/ranges via the OR operator. A typical rule for a number of disjoint ranges looks like:

```
fragment LETTER_WHEN_UNQUOTED:
    '0'..'9'
    | 'A'..'Z'
    | '$'
    | '_'
    | '\u0080'..'\uffff'
;
```

Comment: That's helpful to know, thanks.  As an answer, the question "how DO I approximate this (confirmed missing) operator?" is still up for grabs.

Comment: Updated answer with example, but essentially, you got it on your own already. No problem if you accept your own answer.

Comment: I think I got it.  You helped jolt me onto the right track, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to 'do the math' on set of characters, so that we can define lexical rules which only ever combine characters:

```
lexer grammar RFC2616;

TOKEN: (DIGIT | UPALPHA | LOALPHA | NON_SEPARATORS)+

/* 
 * split up ASCII 0-127 into 'atoms' of 
 * relevance per '2.2 Basic Rules'.  Regions
 * not requiring to be referenced are not 
 * given a name.
 */

//                [\u0000-\u0008];  /* (control chars) */
fragment HT:      '\u0009';         /* (tab) */
fragment LF:      '\u0010';         /* (LF) */
//                 [\u0011-\u0012];  /* (control chars) */
fragment CR:      '\u0013';         /* (CR)
//                [\u0014-\u001f];  /* (control chars) */
fragment SP:      '\u0020';         /* (space) */
//                [\u0021-\u02f];   /* !"#$%'()*+,-./  */
fragment DIGIT:   [u0030-\u0039];   /* 01234556789  */
//                [\u003a-\u0040];  /* :;<=>@  */
fragment UPALPHA: [\u0041-\u005a];  /* ABCDEFGHIGJLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ  */
//                [\u005b-\u0060];  /* [\]^_` */
fragment LOALPHA: [\u0061-\u0071];  /* abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz  */
//                [\u007b-\u007e];  /* {|}~ */
//                '\u007f';         /* (del) */

/* 
 * Considering 'all relevant gaps' and the characters we 
 * cannot use per RFC 2616 Section 2.2 Basic Rules definition 
 * of 'separators', what does that leave us with?  
 * (manually determined)
 */
fragment SEPARATORS: [()<>@,;:\\;"/\[\]?={|}];
fragment NON_SEPARATORS: [!#$%&'*+-.^_`~*];
```

I don't find this approach especially satisfying.  Another rule in RFC 2616 wants to be defined like:

```
TEXT: <any OCTET except CTLs, but including LWS>
qdtext = <any TEXT except <">>
```

This would force me to further refactor up my expedient 'SEPARATORS' token, above, like:

```
fragment QUOT: '"';
fragment SEPARATORS_OTHER_THAN_QUOT: [()<>@,;:\\;/\[\]?={|}];
fragment SEPARATORS: SEPARATORS_OTHER_THAN_QUOT | QUOT;

fragment LWS: SP | HT;

TEXT: DIGIT | UPALPHA | LOALPHA | LWS | SEPARATORS | NON_SEPARATORS;
QDTEXT: DIGIT | UPALPHA | LOALPHA | LWS | SEPARATORS_OTHER_THAN_QUOT | NON_SEPARATORS;
```

Perhaps this is part of the work of writing a lexer, and can't be avoided, but it feels more like solving the problem the wrong way!

(NB: I won't be marking this answer as 'correct'.)

Comment: I think this really does solve the problem 'the hard way', even if one dispenses with (unnecessary) factoring to sub-lexer rules and instead just refers to literal ranges.

Answer (score 0):

Spurred on by the answer from @mike-lischke (because `LETTER_WHEN_UNQUOTED` really felt wrong still), I hunted for the surely-common treatment of quoted string literals in other grammars.  In Terrence Parr's own [Java 1.6 ANTLR3 grammar](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/compiler-grammar/antlrworks/Java.g) (er, not properly served as `text/plain`) (via [ANTLR3 Grammar List](http://www.antlr3.org/grammar/list.html)), he reaches for a 'match any character other than' tilde-operator `~` in a lexer rule:

```
STRINGLITERAL
    :   '"' 
        (   EscapeSequence
        |   ~( '\\' | '"' | '\r' | '\n' )        
        )* 
        '"' 
    ;
// Copyright (c) 2007-2008 Terence Parr and possibly Yang Jiang.
```

> NOTE: the above code is licenced under a BSD licence, but I am *not* re-distributing this fragment under the BSD license (since this post itself is under CC-BY-SA).  Instead, I *am* using it within the terms of 'fair use' as I understand them.

So the `~` gives me an option to express: 'all those characters in Unicode, except those in Set B'.  "Annoying I don't get to choose the set which is excluded from", I thought.  But then I realised

```
TOOHIGH: [\u007f-\uffff];
TOKEN: (~( TOOHIGH | SP | HT | CTRL | SEPARATORS ))+
```

... should be fine.  Although, in practice, ANTLR4 doesn't 'like' lexer sub-rules appearing in 'sets', and only handles sets of literals, so that ultimately becomes:

```
TOKEN:
/* this is given in '2.2 Basic Rules' as:
 *
 *   token          = 1*<any CHAR except CTLs or separators>
 *
 * which I am reducing down to:
 * any character in ASCII 0-127 but _excluding_
 *   CTRL (0-31,127)
 *   SEPARATORS
 *   space (32)
 *   and tab (9)   (which is a CTRL character anyhow)
 */
 ( ~( [\u0000-\u001f] | '\u007f' /*CTRL,HT*/ | [()<>@,;:\\;"/\[\]?={|}] /*SEPARATORS*/ | '\u0020' /*SP*/ | [\u0080-\uffff] /*NON_ASCII*/))*
;
```

The trick was expressing `including the set I do want` (Unicode 0-127) in terms of `excluding the set I don't want` (Unicode 128+).

This is much more succinct than my other answer.  If it actually works, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Right, forgot about the negation operation, but it is still only half the solution, because it always uses the full set of characters as LHS from which the RHS sets are subtracted. It's just the other side of the medal, you can either list all sets that should be included or all those that should be excluded (whatever is smaller, I guess). Not both together.